Write a specific text based on another column content
I'm wondering if it is possible to write specific text according to another column content.
For example I have this column

What I wish to do is that: everytime I wrote mango in column Fruit it will automatically write Green in column Color.
Thank you in advance!

You'd need a lookup table - basically a copy of the table you've shown.  Then, when you type Mango into another cell you can use XLOOKUP / VLOOKUP to look up the colour it should return for that fruit.

You can use a big Select-Case Condition:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Target
        Select Case rng.Formula
            Case "Mango": rng.Offset(0,1).Formula = "Green"
            Case "Apple": rng.Offset(0,1).Formula = "Pink"
            Case "Tangerine": rng.Offset(0,1).Formula = "Orange"
            Case "Cherry": rng.Offset(0,1).Formula = "Red"
    Next rng
End Sub

This will automatically change the Cell Formula right of the Fruit to the selected Color. Those who arent written as a Fruit will be ignored.

can you do it with dim worksheet instead of target?
